# why there is a difference in output in CSS : li a VS li,a

Tags: css, html

why there is a difference in output in CSS:

```
li a
```

from https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM0HPU6L0R35

versus

```
li,a
```

from https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM0HQKZG79HR

Comment: You mean *CSS selectors* not HTML or even HTML 5. Read a bit into CSS and you'll find out very shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's simply because in the first case, the style is applied to all "a" tags found within a li element.

```
li a {
       display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In the second case, the style is applied to all "li" elements as well as to all "a" elements:

```
li,a {
       display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To put it simply, in the second case you get double the padding: 16px from li + 16px from a.

Here are a couple of links on css selectors that you might find useful:

> https://www.sitepoint.com/css-selectors/
>   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Florinache

Instead of writing 2 separate CSS selectors we can combine all these styles into one rule property by separating the individual selectors with a comma like below:

```
li,a {
       display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In your link replace the list with the below code and you will see the difference.

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```